# How can I receive the image id using the media box?

Tags: uploads, images, media, id

The code below allows me to retrieve the image string, when `Insert to Post` has been pressed, but what would be the correct way to retrieve the ID of the image? So I can retrieve all information through `wp_get_attachment_image_src`?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var form_field;
    var upload_field_ID = '';

    jQuery( '.upload_image_button' ).click( function() {

        jQuery( 'html').addClass( 'Image' );

        upload_field_ID = jQuery(this).prev('input');
        form_field      = upload_field_ID.attr( 'name' );

        tb_show( '', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true' );

        return false;

    });

    window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
    window.send_to_editor = function( html ) {

        if (form_field) {
            var image_url = jQuery( 'img', html ).attr( 'src' );
            upload_field_ID.val( image_url );
            tb_remove();
            jQuery( 'html').removeClass( 'Image' );
        } else {
            window.original_send_to_editor( html );
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add in a filter that can add the ID as a html5 data attribute to the returned HTML fragment from send_to_editor.

```
public function image_to_editor($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt){
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

        $x = new DOMXPath($dom);        
        foreach($x->query("//img") as $node){   
            $node->setAttribute("data-id", $id);
        }

        if($dom->getElementsByTagName("a")->length == 0){
            $newHtml = $dom->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0));
        }else{
            $newHtml = $dom->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0));
        }

        return $newHtml;
}

add_filter('image_send_to_editor', array(&$this,'image_to_editor'), 1, 8);
```

Then in your javascript handler for window.send_to_editor;

```
$('img',html).data('id'));
```

You can do the same thing for media uploads as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" name="send[79]" id="send[79]" class="button" value="Insert into Post">
```

Above is an example mark-up of that button. Notice how `name` and `id` fields both contain the image ID.

So with jQuery you can read that.

```
$("...").click(function(){
    var buttonID = $(this).attr("name");
    buttonID = parseInt(buttonID.replace("send[", "").replace("]", ""));
});
```

Comment: You are on fire Brady!

Comment: Hmm it seems that the return is different: <a href="http://www.domein.nl/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Image.jpg"><img src="http://www.domein.nl/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Image.jpg" alt="" title="Image" width="500" height="543" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-16" /></a>

Comment: Need to explain some more as I didn't understand that...

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var form_field;
    var upload_field_ID = '';

    jQuery( '.upload_image_button' ).click( function() {

        jQuery( 'html').addClass( 'Image' );

        upload_field_ID = jQuery(this).prev('input');
        form_field      = upload_field_ID.attr( 'name' );

        tb_show( '', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true' );

        return false;

    });

    window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
    window.send_to_editor = function( html ) {

        if (form_field) {
            var class_string    = jQuery( 'img', html ).attr( 'class' );
            var image_url       = jQuery( 'img', html ).attr( 'src' );
            var classes         = class_string.split( /\s+/ );
            var image_id        = 0;

            for ( var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ ) {
                var source = classes[i].match(/wp-image-([0-9]+)/);
                if ( source && source.length > 1 ) {
                    image_id = parseInt( source[1] );
                }
            }

            alert(image_id); // <---- THE IMAGE ID

            upload_field_ID.val( image_url );
            tb_remove();
            jQuery( 'html').removeClass( 'Image' );
        } else {
            window.original_send_to_editor( html );
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

check it out works find for me.
the thing is that the function tb_show need to know to who pitch the return.  So you just go get the post_id and put it in the url pass to tb_show, if its a new one then you pass it like its a new one.

so i show you my solution just so you can understand better but hey.. easy when you know how

```
jQuery('#uploadPDF').click(
        function() 
        {

             window.send_to_editor = function(html){
                 fileurl = html.toString();
                 jQuery('#path_PDF').val(fileurl);                  
                 tb_remove(); 
            }
             var postId = location.href;
             var startPosition = postId.indexOf("post=");
             var url;

             if (startPosition != -1)
             {
                var postId = postId.substr(startPosition);
                var endPosition = postId.indexOf("&");
                var postId = postId.substring(5, endPosition);//5 POUR POST=

                url = 'media-upload.php?post_id=';

                url = url.concat(postId,'&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
             }
             else
             {
                url = 'media-upload.php?post-new.php?&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true';
             }


             tb_show( '', url);
             return false;
        }
    );
```

Comment: The solution is to get the attachment ID - not the post ID (which you can get in better ways by using `wp_localise_script()` and passing the post ID - from within the `add_meta_box` for example). That way you do not need to extract it from the url.